# Ember.js 1.2 no partials rendered

Tags: ember.js

After upgrading to `Ember 1.2` any of my partials are not rendered. However in the `Ember.TEMPLATES` object they are visible like before. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probally your problem is because [that pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3745).

Now you need to use quotes when referecing a partial by the name:

```
{{partial "my_partial"}}
```

Using without quotes, like `{{partial my_partial}}`, will retrieve the value from `my_partial` property from some controller or model, and when that property change, the template will update to lookup the new partial name.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed that helped - I have old Ember.js app and in the guides partials names were without quotes, now they are with quotes.